# Flutter: Change textField text - created in Android and IOS by PlatformVIew

Tags: swift, flutter, kotlin

How to create `TextView` in Android and IOS with `Flutter PlatformView` (In native) and by clickin elevatedbutton change text of TextView in native?

I've created textview example for Android but I have no idea how to change value (text) of TextField

PS: It already works with initial value, but I don't know how to update text
my code

```
class PlatformWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  const PlatformWidget({super.key, required this.text});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PlatformViewLink(
      viewType: 'INTEGRATION_ANDROID',
      surfaceFactory: (
        BuildContext context,
        PlatformViewController controller,
      ) {
        return AndroidViewSurface(
          controller: controller as AndroidViewController,
          gestureRecognizers: const <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{},
          hitTestBehavior: PlatformViewHitTestBehavior.opaque,
        );
      },
      onCreatePlatformView: (PlatformViewCreationParams params) {
        final ExpensiveAndroidViewController controller =
            PlatformViewsService.initExpensiveAndroidView(
          id: params.id,
          viewType: params.viewType,
          layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          creationParams: {'initialText': text},
          creationParamsCodec: const StandardMessageCodec(),
        );
        controller
          ..addOnPlatformViewCreatedListener(params.onPlatformViewCreated)
          ..create();

        return controller;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter and native (Android/iOS) can communicate with each other through platform channel - as far as I remember (6 months ago), it called `MethodChannel`.

1. Flutter calls to native:

> _methodChannel.invokeMethod('key_1', some_data_here);

2. Android native `NativeView.kt` listens to method channel (iOS the same):

> ```
> override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
>     when (call.method) {
>         "key_1" -> {
>             doSomething1()
>         }
>         "key_2" -> {
>             doSomething2()
>         }
>         else -> {}
>     }
> }
> ```

3. Android native `NativeView.kt` calls back to Flutter:

> methodChannel.invokeMethod("another_key_native", data_call_back)

4. Flutter listens to method channel:

> ```
> initPlatformChannel(int id) {
>     _methodChannel = MethodChannel('${_kViewType}_$id');
>     _methodChannel!.setMethodCallHandler((call) {
>       switch (call.method) {
>         case 'another_key_native_1':
>         case 'another_key_native_2':
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```